# Cells content not shown in JTable until JTable getting focus

Tags: swing, jtable, cellrenderer

Hi have a JTable which each cell is a JPanel (using cell renderer)

The content of the cells is not shown until I click somewhere in the JTable to get focus..
(When I used JTextArea instead of JPanel for each cell it worked well)

I tried to use updateUI() in some places but it didn't help..

What is the problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: can only emphasize @trashgod 's comment - without it's _impossible_ to help. BTW: calling updateUI is _always_ wrong - if its random calling appears to solve a particular problem, something is severely wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
table.repaint();
table.revalidate();
```

Comment: no, typically _not_ needed (except after adding/removing components to/from its parent)

Answer (score 0):

To get functioning controls in a panel, you'll need not just a `TableCellRenderer` but also a `CellEditor`, as seen in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513). As @kleopatra comments, `updateUI()` should *not* be required.