# How to add JRadioButton to group in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I have added radio buttons to a `JTable` using renderer and editor. I have also created group for the same. I'm unable to achieve the exclusiveness (only 1 radio button should be selected) using this principle. Please see my code below and appreciate your response.

Renderer and Editor classes:

```
class RadioButtonRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        return (Component) value;
    }
}

class RadioButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor implements ItemListener {
    private JRadioButton button;

    public RadioButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
        super(checkBox);
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        button = (JRadioButton) value;
        button.addItemListener(this);
        return (Component) value;
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        button.removeItemListener(this);
        return button;
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        super.fireEditingStopped();
    }
}
```

This is where the data is prepared and the grouping is done:

```
private void displayPhoneListShow(Person person) {

    DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel() {
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    Object[] objects = new Object[3];
    Object[] tableColumnNamesPhone = new Object[3];

    tableColumnNamesPhone[0] = "Select";
    tableColumnNamesPhone[1] = "Phone Number";
    tableColumnNamesPhone[2] = "Preferred";

    dm.setColumnIdentifiers(tableColumnNamesPhone);
    ListIterator<Phone> phoneList = person.getPhoneList().listIterator();
    while (phoneList.hasNext()) {
        Phone phone = phoneList.next();
        objects[0] = new JRadioButton(("^"));
        objects[1] = phone.getPhoneNumber();
        objects[2] = phone.getPreferred();
        dm.addRow(objects);
    }
    this.phoneTable.setModel(dm);

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    for (int row = 0; row < dm.getRowCount(); row++) {
        JRadioButton radio = (JRadioButton) dm.getValueAt(row, 0);
        group.add(radio);
    }

    phoneTable.getColumn("Select").setCellRenderer(
            new RadioButtonRenderer());
    phoneTable.getColumn("Select").setCellEditor(
            new RadioButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));
}
```

I am still unable to achieve the result. I have also tried adding `ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup()` as a class variable and also part of the `RadioButtonRenderer` class and added buttons to this group. But results were indifferent.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative, use a `JComboBox` as an [editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox) for mutually exclusive choices within a row. For convenience, [`DefaultCellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html#DefaultCellEditor%28javax.swing.JComboBox%29) offers a constructor especially for this. The  result also makes more efficient use of horizontal space in the row. [`DependentColumn`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513) is an example, shown below. See also these other [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11173600/230513).

1. Figure from @mKorbel's `StatusRenderer` and `StatusEditor`, Mac OS X:

   [image]
2. Figure from a related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513), Mac OS X:

   [image]
3. Figure from @mKorbel's `StatusRenderer` and `StatusEditor`, Windows:

   [image]
4. Figure using `DefaultTableCellRenderer` and `DefaultCellEditor`, Windows (see comments):

   [image]

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class JRadioAsRendererEditor extends JPanel {

    private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {
        "List ID", "Expiration Date", "Status", "Date Created"};
    private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    private static final DateFormat TIME_FORMAT_LONG = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss,SSS");
    private MyTableModel tableModel;
    private JTable table;
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestRadioButtonRenderer");

    public JRadioAsRendererEditor() {
        super(new BorderLayout(0, 5));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        tableModel = new MyTableModel();
        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        table.setDefaultEditor(Date.class, new DateEditor());
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Date.class, new DateRenderer());
        table.setDefaultEditor(Status.class, new StatusEditor());
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Status.class, new StatusRenderer());
// comment the two preceding lines and uncomment the following for a standard editor
// table.setDefaultEditor(Status.class, new DefaultCellEditor(
// new JComboBox(new Status[]{Status.Single, Status.Married, Status.Divorced})));

        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        toolBar.setFloatable(false);
        toolBar.add(new AbstractAction("Add new") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tableModel.add(new TableEntry());
                packTable();
            }
        });
        toolBar.add(new AbstractAction("Remove") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tableModel.remove(table.getSelectedRow());
            }
        });
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.pack();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void packTable() {
        TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
        int columnCount = table.getColumnCount();
        int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
        int[][] preferredHeights = new int[columnCount][rowCount];
        TableCellRenderer renderer;
        Component comp;
        for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++) {
            renderer = columnModel.getColumn(col).getCellRenderer();
            if (renderer == null) {
                renderer = table.getDefaultRenderer(tableModel.getColumnClass(col));
            }
            for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
                comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                    tableModel.getValueAt(row, col), false, false, row, col);
                preferredHeights[col][row] = (int) comp.getPreferredSize().getHeight();
            }
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
            int pref = 0;
            for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++) {
                pref = Math.max(pref, preferredHeights[col][row]);
            }
            table.setRowHeight(row, pref);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JRadioAsRendererEditor tableTestPanel = new JRadioAsRendererEditor();
            }
        });
    }

    private enum Status {

        Single, Married, Divorced;
    }

    private class StatusPanel extends JPanel {

        private JRadioButton theSingleOption;
        private JRadioButton theMarriedOption;
        private JRadioButton theDivorcedOption;
        private ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

        StatusPanel() {
            super(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            setOpaque(true);
            theSingleOption = createRadio(Status.Single);
            theMarriedOption = createRadio(Status.Married);
            theDivorcedOption = createRadio(Status.Divorced);
        }

        private JRadioButton createRadio(Status status) {
            JRadioButton jrb = new JRadioButton(status.toString());
            jrb.setOpaque(false);
            add(jrb);
            buttonGroup.add(jrb);
            return jrb;
        }

        public Status getStatus() {
            if (theMarriedOption.isSelected()) {
                return Status.Married;
            } else if (theDivorcedOption.isSelected()) {
                return Status.Divorced;
            } else {
                return Status.Single;
            }
        }

        public void setStatus(Status status) {
            if (status == Status.Married) {
                theMarriedOption.setSelected(true);
            } else if (status == Status.Divorced) {
                theDivorcedOption.setSelected(true);
            } else {
                theSingleOption.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    }

    private class TableEntry {

        private int instanceNumber;
        private Long theId;
        private Date theExpirationDate;
        private Status theStatus;
        private Date theCreationDate;

        TableEntry() {
            instanceNumber++;
            theId = new Long(instanceNumber);
            theExpirationDate = new Date();
            theStatus = Status.Single;
            theCreationDate = new Date();
        }

        TableEntry(Long anId, Date anExpirationDate, Status aStatus, Date aCreationDate) {
            theId = anId;
            theExpirationDate = anExpirationDate;
            theStatus = aStatus;
            theCreationDate = aCreationDate;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return theId;
        }

        public Date getExpirationDate() {
            return theExpirationDate;
        }

        public Status getStatus() {
            return theStatus;
        }

        public Date getCreationDate() {
            return theCreationDate;
        }

        public void setId(Long anId) {
            theId = anId;
        }

        public void setExpirationDate(Date anExpirationDate) {
            theExpirationDate = anExpirationDate;
        }

        public void setStatus(Status aStatus) {
            theStatus = aStatus;
        }

        public void setCreationDate(Date aCreationDate) {
            theCreationDate = aCreationDate;
        }
    }

    private class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private Vector<Object> theEntries;

        MyTableModel() {
            theEntries = new Vector<Object>();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void add(TableEntry anEntry) {
            int index = theEntries.size();
            theEntries.add(anEntry);
            fireTableRowsInserted(index, index);
        }

        public void remove(int aRowIndex) {
            if (aRowIndex < 0 || aRowIndex >= theEntries.size()) {
                return;
            }
            theEntries.removeElementAt(aRowIndex);
            fireTableRowsDeleted(aRowIndex, aRowIndex);

        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return theEntries.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return Long.class;
                case 1:
                    return Date.class;
                case 2:
                    return Status.class;
                case 3:
                    return Date.class;
            }
            return Object.class;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            TableEntry entry = (TableEntry) theEntries.elementAt(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    try {
                        entry.setId(new Long(Long.parseLong(aValue.toString())));
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        return;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    entry.setExpirationDate((Date) aValue);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    entry.setStatus((Status) aValue);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    entry.setCreationDate((Date) aValue);
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            TableEntry entry = (TableEntry) theEntries.elementAt(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return entry.getId();
                case 1:
                    return entry.getExpirationDate();
                case 2:
                    return entry.getStatus();
                case 3:
                    return entry.getCreationDate();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class DateRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (!(value instanceof Date)) {
                return this;
            }
            setText(DATE_FORMAT.format((Date) value));
            return this;
        }
    }

    private class TimeRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (!(value instanceof Date)) {
                return this;
            }
            setText(TIME_FORMAT_LONG.format((Date) value));
            return this;
        }
    }

    private class DateEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

        private JSpinner theSpinner;

        DateEditor() {
            theSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel());
            theSpinner.setOpaque(true);
            theSpinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(theSpinner, "dd/MM/yyyy"));
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return theSpinner.getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            theSpinner.setValue(value);
            if (isSelected) {
                theSpinner.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else {
                theSpinner.setBackground(table.getBackground());
            }
            return theSpinner;
        }
    }

    private class TimeEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

        private JSpinner theSpinner;
        private Object value;

        TimeEditor() {
            theSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel());
            theSpinner.setOpaque(true);
            theSpinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(theSpinner, "HH:mm:ss,SSS"));
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return theSpinner.getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            theSpinner.setValue(value);
            if (isSelected) {
                theSpinner.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else {
                theSpinner.setBackground(table.getBackground());
            }
            return theSpinner;
        }
    }

    private class StatusEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

        private StatusPanel theStatusPanel;

        StatusEditor() {
            theStatusPanel = new StatusPanel();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return theStatusPanel.getStatus();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            theStatusPanel.setStatus((Status) value);
            if (isSelected) {
                theStatusPanel.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else {
                theStatusPanel.setBackground(table.getBackground());
            }
            return theStatusPanel;
        }
    }

    private class StatusRenderer extends StatusPanel implements TableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setStatus((Status) value);
            if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else {
                setBackground(table.getBackground());
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 right, JComboBox as TableCellEditor for JRadioButtons as TableCellRenderer

Comment: Honestly, I hadn't thought of this, but it's an excellent idea. Please  don't hesitate to post a complementary answer.

Comment: to confirm your initial idea, please change images from Windows Metal to nicer by OSX

Comment: @mKorbel: Sadly the pretty capture doesn't include the popup, hence less pretty, cut & paste hack.

Comment: nitpicks: a) better not by-pass the table's renderer lookup/configuration - instead use getCellRenderer and prepareRenderer b) even if you insist on doing it manually, mixing view and model coordinates might blow (ask the table for the value, not the model) c) probably missing something obvious, but: why the 2d array? slight change of logic and max directly?

Comment: @kleopatra: thank you for critical review; the example needs several more re-factoring passes; I stopped after one. :-) I recall guessing the 2d array was originally part of some more elaborate scheme.