# Calculating dimensions of a cell in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, preferredsize

How can I calculate the dimenstions of the cell in `JTable` containing various components to calculate the height of table dynamically.

For example, I have a table containing multiple checkboxes in the 3rd column and various components in other columns. When new components are added to the cell, then the height and width of the whole table should change dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to ask questions without putting any effort. Could you consider telling us what you've tried at least? Or considered trying?

Comment: @aLearner: Dude i am new to swing and am trying my best, but can't find solutin..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to leverage the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513), which invokes `setRowHeight()` to accommodate the maximal height of each column's renderer.

[image]