# html issues with images in JTable

Tags: java, html, swing, file-io, jtable

I have extendeded AbstractTableModel to create a custom TableModel. The reason for doing this is to bind a hashmap to a JTable.

Within my TableModel, on one of the rows I am returning html code like this:

```
@Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

             switch (columnIndex) {
             case 0:    
                    String sTest = "<div style=\"margin-left:100px;\"><img src='" + new ImageIcon(Wds.class.getResource("/resources/video.png"))+ "'</div>";
                return "<html>" + sTest + sTest + "hello" + "</html>";              

             default:
                    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
             }    
        }
```

The problem I have now is that the html support in Java seems to be pretty bad.

I need to control the images using "margin-left, margin-top" etc. The issue is that if I use `"<div style>"` it will lead to a linebreak, so everything afterwards will be one row below. If I use `"<span style>"` it doesn't lead to a linebreak, but margin doesn't work with `"<span style>"` (which it should);

I have also tried creating custom TableCellRenderer and add the .css values there and using `"<div class>"` but the issue with the linebreak remains.

Usually `"display:inline"` in `"<div style>"` eliminates the line-break and `margin-left` usually works with `"<span style>"`, but it seems Java has pretty poor HTML support.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I can solve this?

Here is full SSCCE code:

```
private Map<String, String> list = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private String[] columnNames = {"Column1"}; 

        public void addElement(String sElement, String sElement2) {         

            list.put(sElement, sElement2);
            fireTableRowsInserted(list.size(), list.size());

        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

             switch (columnIndex) {
             case 1:    
                    String sTest = "<div style=\"margin-left:100px;\"><img src='" + new ImageIcon(Wds.class.getResource("/resources/video.png"))+ "'</div>";
                    return "<html>" + sTest + sTest + "hello" + "</html>";

             default:
                    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
             }    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the alignment in a [custom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) `TableCellRenderer`, for [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer). The example shows a `ListCellRenderer`, but the principle is the same.

Addendum: *I need to add several icons and position them differently within the cell.*

Your implementation of `TableCellRenderer` can return any desired `Component`—even a `JPanel` with its own layout, such as the `StatusPanel` shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513). You may also need a custom `TableCellEditor`.

Comment: I can't do it like that, since I need to add several icons and position them differently within the cell.

Comment: If the HTML support in `DefaultTableCellRenderer` is inadequate, I don't see another choice; more above.