# Clickable html link in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have looked everywhere without finding an answer. Sorry if this has been posted before.

I know how to do a clickable URL when the cell itself only contains a URL, which basically just attaching a mouselistener to a table and getting which Row is clicked and getting the value. So that's easy.

My issue is that I have several links inside one cell so I need different things to happen when the user click on those links. For example:

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

@Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

             switch (columnIndex) {
             case 0:
                  return "<html><a href='www.test.com'>test1</a> <a href='www.test2.com'>test2</a></html>";

             default:
                    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
             }    
        }
}
```

So I have two different links that need to be next to eachother. How do I find out which one of them got clicked?

Finding out which row was clicked is not difficult, but how do I find out which element inside the row was clicked?

Edit: Can't use JEditorPane since it messes up the objects inside the cells.

Comment: Duplicate of [html issues with images in JTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209322/html-issues-with-images-in-jtable).

Comment: Its not duplicaste. This is for multiple urls being clicked in cells, the other one is for positioning HTML elements (images) without a line brake.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to make cell as JEditorpane. As you mentioned your using cell(may be its Jtable) make the jtable custom and editable cells.

Chk out this links:

[JtextPane](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/331500/how-can-i-add-a-clickable-url-in-a-jtextpane)

[Tutorial](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JEditorPane.html)

Comment: I can't use a JEditorPane, it completely messes up the cells when loading several elements :(

Comment: @Omid: Please edit your question to include such requirements.