# How to set table height outside the cellrenenderer in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

Good Morning everyone. I have a Multilinecellrenenderer which is changing the height of the jtable row based on the content of the cell.

```
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object
        value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    setText(value.toString());//or something in value, like value.getNote()...
    if (isSelected) {
        setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
        setForeground(table.getForeground());
        setBackground(table.getBackground());
    }
    setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(),
            getPreferredSize().height);
    if (table.getRowHeight(row) <= getPreferredSize().height) {
            table.setRowHeight(row, getPreferredSize().height);
    }
    return this;
}
```

I understand that modifying the jtable inside the renderer make it run in infinite loop and that is happening in my code which I verified using the logs statements. I also understand that I can modify the row height during adding content of the model and I have tried everything I knew but I am not able to set the height of the row outside the renenderer. Could anyone please help me how can I call `table.setRowHeight(int,int)` outside the cell renenderer.

I am adding the content of the model dynamically using following statement

```
   for(ProductRow object: data){
       model.addRow(new Object[]{object.getProductNumber(),object.getDescription(),
               object.getLastTouchedOn(),object.getLastTouchedBy()});
       }
```

I just do not know how to get the current row number and preferred height. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513).

Comment: @trashgod make as an answer :D

Comment: @nachokk packTable() method in his example works perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mKorbel shows in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513), you can derive the desired size for `setRowHeight()` from the preferred sizes of enclosed components. Be sure to include a subsequent call to `pack()` the enclosing frame.