# Paint jtable cell editor above jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Designing a custom JTable I already know that DefaultCellEditor admits a JComboBox in his constructor. This JComboBox, when clicked to display the list items, shows above the other cells of the  JTable. The problem is that I need a more sophisticated behavior as what JComboBox offers, so that I've implemented a JTextField with a JList and a JButton, when the JButton gets clicked (or the user enters text in the JTextField) the elements in the JList become visible. This 3 elements are in a JPanel. When I try to use this panel as a cell editor (extending AbtractCellEditor and implementing TableCellEditor) the elements in the list show inside the editing cell but I cannot mimic the behavior of the DefaultCellEditor with the combo so that the list elements show above the JTable.

Here I define the custom cell editor: (very short version);

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class CustomCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements     TableCellEditor {
private JList list;
private JButton button;
private JTextField editor;
private JPanel mainPanel;

public CustomCellEditor() {
    list = new JList(new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" });
    editor = new JTextField();
    button = new JButton("Click me ");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            list.setVisible(!list.isVisible());
        }
    });

    JPanel auxPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    auxPanel.add(editor, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    auxPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);
    mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.add(auxPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return editor.getText();
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    return mainPanel;
}
```

}

And this a main program with a jtable with this panel as a cell editor:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class CustomTable {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            CustomTable instance = new CustomTable();
            instance.createAndShowUI();
        }
    });
}

private void createAndShowUI() {       
    JTable table = new JTable(new CustomTableModel());
    //So that I can see the contents of the list when edited
    table.setRowHeight(60);
    TableColumn editableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    editableColumn.setPreferredWidth(250);
    editableColumn.setCellEditor(new CustomCellEditor());
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);     
}

private class CustomTableModel extends AbstractTableModel   {
    private final String[] columnNames = {"Editable column", "Other column"};

    private final Object[][] data = {
        {"Ricardo", "Mr."},
        {"Josefina", "Ms."}
    };

            @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        if (0 == col)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        data[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

}
```

}

Can someone help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: People in SO will very happy to help you but you must show your work first :) Or even better, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating your problem.

Comment: well nice description, for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded data for JTable in local variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `JComboBox` as a table editor relies on it being a button that displays a popup component when pressed. As you have several components in a cell, consider these alternatives:

- Add the components to a panel, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513) for a group of `JRadioButton` instances.
- Add the components to a modal dialog, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3591230/230513) using `JDialog`.

Comment: Thanks trashgod, the modal dialog can be a workaround, but it remains a kind of a mistery to me how DefaultCellEditor accomplishes to show the list of the combo above the cells of the jtable

Comment: @RicharddeOlba: The `JComboBox` UI delegate for a given L&F (typically) contains a `BasicComboPopup` that extends `JPopupMenu`.