# Jspinner inside Jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jspinner

I have a `Jtable` with two columns, first column is a `JTextField` and the second column is a `JSpinner`.. While I am using tab key to navigate from `JTextField` to `JSpinner`, the `JTextField` inside the `Jspinner` is not editable and it is not responding for the key actions and the editor is not present in the `jspinner`?

Please help me..Thanks in advance Vishwa

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help

Comment: 1. read Oracle tutorial about How to use Tables, part editors and renderers, 2. then search here (will be useless without reading tutorial, understanding those concepts)

Comment: Some related examples are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513).