# Last JCheckBox stays toggled when firing changes in my JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I have a table model containing elements of type JCheckBox. I want the content of this table to be different according to the value of a JComboBox.

My problem is the following : if I toggle a few checkboxes and then change the value of my combo box, all the check boxes take the default value (this is what I want, because the boolean values are those of the selected item in the JCheckBox) except the last one I toggled before changing the value of the combo box.

And here is how I implemented this :

```
public class ValsSelectionTableModel extends MyAbstractTableModel {

    private final JComboBox<Data> dataField;
    private final Map<Data, JCheckBox[][]> modifiedVals = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Data data = (Data) dataField.getSelectedItem();
        if (!modifiedVals.containsKey(data))
            modifiedVals.put(data,
                buildCheckBoxesFrom(ClassWithStaticFields.defaultBoolArray));
        return modifiedVals.get(data)[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }

    private JCheckBox[][] buildCheckBoxesFrom(boolean[][] boolArray) {
        JCheckBox[][] checkBoxArray = 
            new JCheckBox[boolArray.length][boolArray[0].length];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < checkBoxArray.length ; i++)
            for (int j = 0 ; j < checkBoxArray[i].length ; j++) {
                checkBoxArray[i][j] = new JCheckBox();
                checkBoxArray[i][j].setSelected(boolArray[i][j]);
                checkBoxArray[i][j].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            }
        return checkBoxArray;
    }
}
```

Has anyone got an idea what's wrong with this ?

EDIT : I forgot something important (otherwise the JComboBox selection would not change the display) : I added this actionListener to my JComboBox :

```
public class MyListener implements ActionListener {

    private final ValsSelectionTableModel tableModel;

    public MyListener(ValsSelectionTableModel tableModel) {
        this.tableModel = tableModel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Manage elements of type `Boolean` in your `TableModel` to get the default [editor/renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Comment: @trashgod Actually I already tried with Boolean, but the rendered checkboxes cannot be toggled. Do I have to set the default editor of the table for Boolean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manage elements of type `Boolean` in your `TableMode` to get the default [renderer and editor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

> I already tried with Boolean, but the rendered checkboxes cannot be toggled.

Your implementation of `TableMode` appears to extend [`AbstractTableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data); ensure that the following things happen for the relevant column:

- Return `Boolean.class` from `getColumnClass()`.
- Return `true` from `isCellEditable()`.
- Fire the appropriate `TableModelEvent` in `setValueAt()` when updating your internal `Map<…>`.

Complete examples using `AbstractTableModel` are seen [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#eg) and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table). An example of adding multiple components to a column is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513).

Comment: Works perfectly well, I was missing `setValueAt()`, which I didn't know existed since I did not have to use it for my other tables.
Thanks a lot ! However I still can't see what was happening in my original code (with JCheckBox).

Comment: @Paco: Glad you got it working; if `getColumnClass()` returns `Boolean.class`, you'll get a `JCheckBox` as the renderer by default.