# Fill JTable with 1d-to-2d list, and restrict to property of Object

Tags: java, swing, loops, jtable

I have a list of elements that in turn are lists of elements:

```
{{entity1, entity2}, {}, {entity3}, {entity4}, {entity5, entity6, entity7}, {}, ...}
```

I want to convert this list to a JTable. The list is 36 long, which should translate to a table of 6 by 6. Let's assume that the above example is a table of 3x2, the result'd be:

```
_______________________________
| entity1 |         | entity3 |
| entity2 |         |         |
|_________|_________|_________|
| entity4 | entity5 |         |
|         | entity6 |         |
|         | entity7 |         |
|_________|_________|_________|
```

Side note, each entity is an object itself (e.g. employee object), and I'd want to output only a specific property of the entities (e.g. `.firstName` or something similar). Maybe this can be done with `.map`? But unfortunately I'm not all too familiar with that.

What I got so far, is a loop for the initial list. Let's assume the outer list is called location (i.e. 36 locations) and the inner elements are employees on specific locations. (In practice the entities are in an arraylist, and the locations in an array.) This is untested, but it seems easy enough that it should work? (Please tell me if it's not.)

```
Location[] locations; // 36 locations
Location[][] locations2d; // new array 6x6
for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
  for(int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
    locations2d[x][y] = locations[6*x+y];
  }
}
```

But how do I now easily get this `2dlocations` into my 6x6 JTable, considering I only want the `.firstName` of the entities in that list?

---

Trying some stuff out, I came up with this:

```
public Overview() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 239);
        contentPane.add(tabbedPane);

        // Create new scrollpane
        JScrollPane scrollPaneEntityOverview = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPaneEntityOverview.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        // Set entity location data to table
        Object[][] data = locationToTable();
        JTable table = new JTable(data, null); // 1

        // Create new scrollpane, initialize with table
        JScrollPane scrollPaneMap = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPaneMap.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        tabbedPane.addTab("Entity overview", null, scrollPaneEntityOverview, null);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Map", null, scrollPaneMap, null);
    }

    public Object[][] locationToTable() {
        Object[][] data = new Object[6][6];
        Location[] locations = WorldMap.getInstance().getLocations();
        for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
                data[x][y] = locations[6*x+y];
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to add the table to a scrollpane, which is part of a tabbed window. However, when trying this out the tab is empty: nothing shows. Furthermore, I also get the following NullPointerException, which links to `//1` in the snippet above:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.JTable$1.getColumnCount(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.createDefaultColumnsFromModel(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.setModel(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JTable.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at game.Overview.<init>(Overview.java:59)
    at game.Overview$1.run(Overview.java:29)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: *"I want to convert this list to a jTable."*  Does not seem a good fit for a `JTable` (also note the case of class name).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Edited the case. But why isn't it a good fit?

Comment: Because it is (fundamentally) for multiple rows of a single entity.  Everything about table has been specialized for showing rows each devoted to aspects or properties of that one record.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well, in a way it is: each cell is a location with a coordinate (0,0 etc.) and at that location there are employees. What else would you propose?

Comment: If you have a look at the [`DefaultTableModel`'s constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel(java.lang.Object[][],%20java.lang.Object[])), you will see that you can simply pass a 2D array of data (in the form of row/columns). See [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried some stuff out, but I run into some issues. First of all a NullPointerexception, and second : well, nothing happens! There's no data shown in the table.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't have a variable name start with a number `2dlocations` change it to `locations2d` for example, this could lead to some problems in the future.

Comment: @Frakcool Thanks, edited.

Comment: Stop using a null layout, this can lead to more problems, instead try with a [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) or combinations of them. See [Null Layout is Evil](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-java/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html) and [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing)

Comment: For better help sooner please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with hardcoded values and no dependencies, which we can copy-paste and see the same issues as you, following my above recommendations, this will get you more and better responses and less confusion

Comment: @BramVanroy You will need to supply columns, otherwise the `JTable` will display nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in [*Creating a Table Model*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), this is a good case for extending `AbstractTableModel`. For some arbitrary `Entity`,

```
class Entity extends Object {…}
```

model your data a list of lists:

```
class EntityModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    public EntityModel(List<List<Entity>> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    List<List<Entity>> data;

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return data.get(0).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        List list = data.get(row);
        return list.get(col);
    }
```

Override `getColumnName()` as desired. A complete example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513). Refine the appearance of each cell using a suitable [renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) as required, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513).

Comment: Also consider a `List<ListModel<Entity>>` and a `GridLayout(2, 3)` containing `JList`.