# CellEditor with JSpinner Time format reverts to date format

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor, tablecolumn

I'm trying to create a `DefaultCellEditor` for my `JTable`'s column so that I can set the start time and end time of a schedule.
However, I can't figure out why is it that when I input the time using the `JSpinner` in `JTable`'s cell, I see the correct formatting for picking time but when I press enter or deselects the current cell, *I get an entire date instead of just the time*.

Here's my `DefaultCellEditor` with `JSpinner`.

```
public class ScheduleCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

    private final JSpinner timeSpinner;

    public ScheduleCellEditor() {
        super(new JTextField());
        timeSpinner = new JSpinner();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Date date = new Date();
        SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        model.setValue(calendar.getTime());
        timeSpinner.setModel(model);

        JSpinner.DateEditor editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(timeSpinner, "HH:mm");
        DateFormatter formatter = (DateFormatter) editor.getTextField().getFormatter();
        formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
        formatter.setOverwriteMode(true);

        timeSpinner.setEditor(editor);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        return timeSpinner;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return timeSpinner.getValue();
    }

}
```

And here's how I set the `DefaultCellEditor` to `JTable` `TableColumn`s

```
    TableColumnModel columnModel = jtblSchedule.getColumnModel();
    TableColumn startTimeCol = columnModel.getColumn(1);
    TableColumn endTimeCol = columnModel.getColumn(2);
    startTimeCol.setCellEditor(new ScheduleCellEditor());
    endTimeCol.setCellEditor(new ScheduleCellEditor());
```

When I click the cell and pick the time, it shows correct formatting where I only see **HH:mm**

[image]

When I click out of the cell or click somewhere else, I get the full date even when the editor and model is formatted to time.

[image]

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this. I just need the time to show and not the complete date.

I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `TableCellEditor` seems to be in order, but you're still getting the default [renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for the time value. You'll need a [custom renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) with a suitable [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Adapted from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513), perhaps something like this:

```
private static final DateFormat TIME_FORMAT = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
…
private class TimeRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, selected, focused, row, column);
        setText(TIME_FORMAT.format((Date) value));
        return this;
    }
}
…
TimeRenderer timeRenderer = new TimeRenderer();
startTimeCol.setCellRenderer(timeRenderer);
endTimeCol.setCellRenderer(timeRenderer);
```