# Updating Java-Swing GUI in-between adding very big components

Tags: java, swing

I am facing the problem that I want to add several big components (each big component = 15k JPanel with each 10 JLabel) to a JFrame. After each big component has been added, I want to update a label that shows a counter of how many of these big components has already been added.

Here is a small example which should illustrate the problem:

```java
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            // preparation
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            final Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
            contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            final JLabel loadingLabel = new JLabel("Loading 0/5");
            contentPane.add(loadingLabel);

            // start GUI
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            // adding big components and show progress
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                final long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                contentPane.add(getBigJPanel());
                System.out.println("time <i=" + i + ">: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
                loadingLabel.setText("Loading " + i + "/5");
                contentPane.revalidate();
                contentPane.repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    private static JPanel getBigJPanel() {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        for (int i = 0; i < 25_000; i++) {
            panel.add(new JPanel());
        }
        return panel;
    }

}
```

I have the label `loadingLabel` which should show the number of big components already added. It is added to a JFrame at the start and directly after that the UI should start and be visible. However, because right after `frame.setVisible(true)` the code starts to add the big components, the label is not painted. I assume that Swing tries to optimize the code and don't waste a `repaint` when new components are added directly after.

Furthermore, after each big component has been added, I update the text of the label and call `revalidate();repaint();` which should update the GUI. Nevertheless, no progress is show. Only after every big component has been added, the last `loadingLabel` is shown (should be "Loading 5/5").

What I want is that the GUI shows each of the "Loading i/5".

P.S.: I added a time measurement to show how long it takes to create a big component and to add it to the content pane. On my PC it yields about 3000 ms each time. The problem is only relevant if it yields a high time. That means to try the problem on a powerful PC you might need to increase the `25_000` of `getBigJPanel()`.

One thing I tried was to somewhat rearrange the operations of the EDT by wrapping blocks of codes with `SwingUitilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`. On the one hand, it seems to work fine so far, however, on the other hand, it leaves a total mess, because it requires recursively calling the next iteration in a new `SwingUitilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`.

Instead of the for loop:

```java
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    loadingLabel.setText("Loading " + 1 + "/5");
    contentPane.revalidate();
    contentPane.repaint();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        contentPane.add(getBigJPanel());
        loadingLabel.setText("Loading " + 2 + "/5");
        contentPane.repaint();
        contentPane.revalidate();
        contentPane.repaint();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            contentPane.add(getBigJPanel());
            loadingLabel.setText("Loading " + 3 + "/5");
            etc.
        });
    });
});
```

I also looked at `SwingWorker`, but I think this class is designed for time-consuming tasks apart from doing something on the EDT.

Comment: I’m guessing these 25,000 panels do not contain any input fields, since no human user could possibly deal with that many.  If that’s the case, and if everyone of these 25,000 panels is expected to have the same size, you can make this lightning-fast by making just one instance of a subclass of JPanel, with an overridden paintComponent method, instead of creating and adding so many child components.

Comment: Don't create 25K components. Instead you should be using a JTable or JList to display the data. *I also looked at SwingWorker, but I think this class is designed for time-consuming tasks apart from doing something on the EDT.* - so you use the "doInBackground" method to create the child components. Then you "publish" the component once you have finished creating it. This is exactly the reason for using a SwingWorker. That is to remove a long running task from the EDT.

Comment: Leverage _flyweight_ rendering like the examples examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179669/230513).

Answer (score 0):

- When you call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->` that will run the code inside the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) which is responsible for updating the UI.
- So while that keeps running (your code running inside the EDT), no GUI will be updated.
- So, you can construct GUI elements in normal threads (other that the EDT), as long as they're not displayed. BUT keep in mind to only access those elements from that one and same thread!
- As soon as you're done and want to display it, let the EDT have it

=> So, utilize that, do the construction outside, and only put things into the EDT that are "ready to go":

```
package stackoverflow.gui.edt.bigpanels;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // preparation
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        final JLabel loadingLabel = new JLabel("Loading 0/5");
        contentPane.add(loadingLabel);

        // start GUI
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // adding big components and show progress
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            final int showIndex = i;
            final long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final JPanel newBigLabel = getBigJPanel();
            System.out.println("time <i=" + showIndex + ">: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                contentPane.add(newBigLabel);
                loadingLabel.setText("Loading " + showIndex + "/5");
                contentPane.revalidate();
                contentPane.repaint();
            });
        }
    }

    private static JPanel getBigJPanel() {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        for (int i = 0; i < 25_000; i++) {
            panel.add(new JPanel());
        }
        return panel;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swing is single threaded and not thread safe.  This means that you shouldn't be performing long running/blocking operations within the context of the event dispatching thread and you shouldn't be updating the UI or state the UI relies on from out side the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

So, the problem is not know exactly why you're trying to do what you're doing.

If, for example, if you're trying to load data in the background, which you want to then display to the UI, an overall better solution would be to decouple your UI from your data/data management.

This means that you can load/process the data in a seperate thread(s), which allows the your UI to remain responsive.  The issue then becomes safely passing the data back to the Event Dispatching Thread context.  Again, multiple ways you might do this, but the simplest solution would be make use of a `SwingWorker`.

This would allow to "do work" in the background and provides capabilities to sync the updates back to the EDT.

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        private JLabel progressLabel = new JLabel("...");
        private JPanel containerPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel headerPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            add(headerPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            add(new JScrollPane(containerPane));

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            headerPane.add(progressLabel, gbc);

            JButton btn = new JButton("Make it so");
            headerPane.add(btn, gbc);

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    progressLabel.setText("...");
                    containerPane.removeAll();
                    btn.setEnabled(false);

                    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Object, Object>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                            for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                                // This is just simulation of work
                                // taking time to run
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                                setProgress(index);
                                publish(index);
                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void process(List<Object> chunks) {
                            containerPane.add(new BigPane());
                            containerPane.revalidate();
                            containerPane.repaint();
                        }
                    };
                    worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                            if (!(evt.getSource() instanceof SwingWorker)) {
                                return;
                            }
                            SwingWorker worker = (SwingWorker) evt.getSource();
                            String propertyName = evt.getPropertyName();
                            if ("state".equals(propertyName) && worker.isDone()) {
                                btn.setEnabled(true);
                            } else if ("progress".equals(propertyName)) {
                                progressLabel.setText(Integer.toString(worker.getProgress()));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    worker.execute();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class BigPane extends JPanel {
        public BigPane() {
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details

If, on the other hand, you just want to display some type of animation, I'd probably just make use of a Swing `Timer` instead, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        private JLabel progressLabel = new JLabel("...");
        private JPanel containerPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel headerPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            add(headerPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            add(new JScrollPane(containerPane));

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            headerPane.add(progressLabel, gbc);

            JButton btn = new JButton("Make it so");
            headerPane.add(btn, gbc);

            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    progressLabel.setText("...");
                    containerPane.removeAll();
                    btn.setEnabled(false);

                    Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                        private int count = -1;

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            count++;
                            if (count == 4) {
                                btn.setEnabled(false);
                                ((Timer) (e.getSource())).stop();
                            }
                            progressLabel.setText(Integer.toString(count + 1));
                            containerPane.add(new BigPane());
                            containerPane.revalidate();
                            containerPane.repaint();
                        }
                    });
                    timer.setInitialDelay(500);
                    timer.start();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public class BigPane extends JPanel {
        public BigPane() {
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details